# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is usually an issue of unbalanced parens and curly braces, however after carefully sifting through my syntax, I have, to the best of my ability, confirmed the correct parity of each of these scope delimiters and have no other recourse except to allow my fellow S.O. pundits to take a gander at the following:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/application/get_programs_for_center",
      type: "POST",
      data: formdata,
      success: function(response){
       var options = $("#school_application_program_name");
       var result = JSON.parse(response);
       console.log(result);
       $.each(result, function() {
          options.append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));
        });
      }
  });
```

N.B. the error is being thrown in the *middle* of the line `var result = JSON.parse(response);` specifically immediately after `JSON.`

Comment: It's not in the *line*, the error is thrown by the called `JSON.parse` function itself because `response` is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that what you parse isn't JSON.

And the reason it's not JSON, is that the `response` argument you receive is *already* parsed from JSON by jQuery. Don't parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse **JSONArray**, jQuery will not parse it into Object directly, you have to use  JSON.parse(response)

However, if you parse a **JSONObject**, it will be identified and parse into Object automatically
So keep it in mind, that will help you!